# DJANGO avoid repeating date on DateTime calculation

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have managed to create a very simple model which allows me to subtract 2 DateTime fields, like so:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    take = models.DateTimeField()
    land = models.DateTimeField()
    tot = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='00000')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

    def time_delta(self):
        tdelta = self.land - self.take
        return str(tdelta)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tot = self.time_delta()
        super(Log, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My problem is the user would have to specify the date on every field. How could I make the fields `take` and `land` refer to `date` once and for all?

Comment: Do you mean that at initialisation, the *take* and *land* fields are initialised with the *date* value?

Comment: This needs a little re-wording to be answerable. Perhaps try phrasing the last part differently, or alternatively describe the purpose of the code to give context.

Comment: I'm not quite grasping your question. It sounds like you want `take` and `land` to be *properties* which refer to `date` so you only store the date once. But then your time delta would make no sense, because then the time_delta would always be 0, wouldn't it?

Comment: Couldn’t you just make `take` and `land` `TimeField` instead?

Comment: As @laurent laporte says it, take and land are initialised  with date.Eventually these fields will go in a form for users to enter take off time and landing time in a logbook. So they would enter: date of flight, then take off time and then landing time the form would calculate the flight time. The problem is, at the moment, a user would have to enter 'take' and 'land' in the form as a date and time rather than time only. 2ps: if I do that my simple calculation doesn't work, because subtracting times in python needs datetime.... I hope i made things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know how to do that in your Django model. I think you have to calculate the dates and times in your controller instead, and then register the values in your database.

You can do something like that with [datetime.datetime.combine()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) function:

> Return a new datetime object whose date components are equal to the given date object’s, and whose time components are equal to the given time object’s.

You have a reference date, for instance: today.

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date.today()
```

The user enter the takeoff time, you can combine this time with the reference date.

```
takeoff_time = datetime.time(8, 12)
takeoff_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(date, takeoff_time)
print(takeoff_datetime.isoformat(" "))
# -> 2016-12-21 08:12:00
```

If the landing date is the same as the takeoff date, you can calculate the landing date/time with the same *date* reference:

```
landing_time = datetime.time(12, 37)
landing_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(date, landing_time)
print(landing_datetime.isoformat(" "))
# -> 2016-12-21 12:37:00
```

Then, you can register the *date*, _takeoff_datetime_ and _landing_datetime_ in your database.

*Note: you can do the same with the flight duration*

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to find a solution largely based on Laurent's answer so here it is,if that can ever help someone else:

```
from datetime import datetime


def calculation(self):
    calc_take_off = datetime.combine(self.date, self.take)
    calc_land = datetime.combine(self.date, self.land)
    result = calc_land - calc_take_off
    return str(result)
```

and then to save this in models:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.tot = self.calculation()
    super(Log, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```